# разделение стоки на объект javascript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Нужна помощь в разделении строки вида:
`"1:привет:12:хаха:87:ааа"`
в объект вида:
`{
   1: "привет",
   12: "хаха",
   87: "ааа"
}`

Comment: Что Вы уже предприняли в этом направлении?

Comment: Пока что я пытался разделить с помощью .split(/[^]*:[^]*/ig)
Но естественно не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var str = "1:привет:12:хаха:87:ааа";
var parts = str.split(":");
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i = i + 2) {
  result[parts[i]] = parts[i + 1];
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)) Все работает!

Comment: @Дмитрий Пожалуйста. Успехов. Через 10 минут Вы сможете отметить этот ответ как принятый (знак "галочка" слева от ответа).

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаю